# List PHP scripts by CPU time

Tags: php, performance, wordpress, cpu-usage

This may be something that belongs on ServerFault, but I'm not completely certain.

I'm trying to diagnose performance problems on a WordPress install that consistently runs at around 88% CPU load, with 3-8 PHP processes running at any one time (sometimes a few of which are marked as `<DEFUNCT>`.)

I already have APC installed, WP Super Cache/WP Widget Cache installed.

Is there a way to determine exactly where the bottlenecks are coming from, ideally with a script name or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may look at the profiling with the XDebug extension: http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: That's amazing. I've Googled for this multiple times and never gotten anywhere! My search-fu is weak. XDebug looks awesome, thanks. :)